# How to "talk" with a bot framework from code?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, botframework, chatbot

I have a bot framework published on Azure that is working fine, according to my emulator. I developed this bot to use it on the app (Xamarin) that I am developing (C#). However, I don't know how to communicate with my bot. I need someway to send "strings" and get the "strings" answered by the bot. How can I establish a connection and a conversation with my bot?

Any code tutorial available?

My bot is published on https://XXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/messages .

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will have to use the [Direct Line API](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline/).

> The Direct Line API is a simple REST API for connecting directly to a single bot. This API is intended for developers writing their own client applications, web chat controls, mobile apps, or service-to-service applications that will talk to their bot

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLine) you will find a sample showing how to create a DirectLine client.

Comment: But how can I use it? I didn't see any code example of how I should use the Direct Line API

Comment: I updated the post to include a pointer to a sample showing how to use it.